# Disabling monitor on an headless virtual machine

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualbox, monitor, headless

I set up a virtual machine with Ubuntu Server edition.
When I boot it up, the output from the console appears on VirtualBox's virtual screen. This means the machine is wasting resources trying to display output on a screen. It's just a text terminal, I know, but it still requires resources. Why waste them when I'm going to only access remotely through PuTTY?

I know that VirtualBox can start a virtual machine in "headless" mode, but I fear it will just disable VirtualBox's output window, with no real impact on the virtual machine itself.

My questions are:

- Will my virtual machine still detect a monitor attached when it runs in headless mode?
- If so, how big is the performance impact of this situation? Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: Did you install a desktop environment on it?

Comment: No desktop environment right now, but I may install a VNC server in the future.

Comment: Then it does not require any additional resources. Just a tty which is already present. Every Linux system that I know starts 7 ttys by default.

Comment: So I'm worrying about nothing. :) Sorry for the noob question!

Comment: Will post the former comment as an answer. Might help somebody... However, the question is better suited for http://superuser.com

Comment: Sorry for posting on the wrong site! However, I marked the answer as correct. Thanks!

Comment: Ok! :) Just to let you know: I voted for close in the hope it gets migrated to superuser, not to harm you. I think the question is not bad but really belongs there. Don't known why it didn't have been migrated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not require any additional resources. Just a tty device and a blocking [`getty`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getty_%28Unix%29) process which requires no CPU resources and which has would both have been created anyway. (Every Linux system that I know starts 6 ttys by default).